# Postman is not enabled to communicate with the api

Tags: node.js, azure, api, postman, azure-virtual-machine

I'm running my node.js api on Azure virtual machine, also at that virtual machine there is an sql server, my api is running, and when I'm trying to send a request from postman on my pc to the cloud virtual machine it's giving error connect ETIMEDOUT, I'm new to the backend development and also cloud concept, I tried to allow inbound traffic to api port (8090) on azure virtual machine but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Could you goto settings and try putting max size and timeout as 0

Comment: No effect, nothing changed & still connection error is appearing.